# Problems with atoi in c++/cli

Tags: arrays, c++-cli

```
array<String^>^ rekordininkai = gcnew array<String^>(100);
array<Int32>^ man = gcnew array<Int32>(100);

int j=0;
int n=1;
for (int m=0;m<z;m++)
                    {

                        man[n] = atoi(rekordininkai[n]);
                        rikiavimas(man,i);
                        listBox1->Items->Add(rekordininkai[j] + " " + rekordininkai[n]);
                        j=j+2;
                        n=n+2;
                    }
```

So what's wrong with this line? The error is : 'atoi' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'System::String ^' to 'const char *'

```
man[n] = atoi(rekordininkai[n]);
```

Comment: As the error says, you're passing a System.String reference to a function that expects a `char*`. Aside from string representation (C++ expects a trailing NUL to terminate a string), the main issue is that a .NET string is in unicode, so more like a C++ `wchar_t*`. So instead of atoi, use something managed, like `Int32::Parse()` instead.

Comment: @Zastai FWIW, .NET strings also have a null terminator in addition to the character count field, to ease compatibility. There are techniques which let you use .NET strings as a  `const wchar_t*` without copying memory around.

Answer (score 3):

If you're writing .Net code, *write .Net code*. In general, don't mess around with the C++ way of doing things when there's a .Net method available.

There are several methods to convert a .Net `String^` to an integer. [`Int32::TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx?cs-lang=cpp) is probably the most appropriate one to use.

Side note: If you're just learning C++, I'd recommend that you either learn plain C++, or learn a fully-managed language like C#. C++/CLI is intended for interoperability, not for primary development; it has all the complexities of C++, all the complexities of C#, and a few of its own.